# Bash not recognized — impossible to execute compilation script in shell

Tags: python, bash, powershell, shell

Impossible to compile shell script with bash because "The term "bash" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."

I am currently facing an issue when trying to compile a shell script using Visual Studio Code on Windows. I followed the instructions provided, but I keep getting errors. I tried using the "bash" and "sh" commands in the built-in terminal, but neither of them seem to be recognized as a valid command.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/ch
echo "Compilando MixMaster MOD"
gcc -shared -w -m32 -pthread -Wall -static Injection.cpp Script.cpp CScriptManager.cpp CMemory.cpp CHookManager.cpp CEventsHandler.cpp liblua52.a -ldl -o ../Injection.so -masm=intel
```

Here is the basic command I use in the built-in compiler terminal:

```
bash compile.sh
```

However, I get an error message stating: "The term "bash" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."

Comment: Windows doesn't come with any unix-style shell applications out of the box, you'll need to install one yourself (either directly in Windows, or, perhaps preferably, [using WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install))

Comment: Did your instructions mention anything about the feasibility of doing this on Windows?

Comment: First of all, the #! line `#!/bin/ch` does not make sense, but since you explicitly invoke the script using `bash`, this should not be a problem. However, the wording of the error message makes me suspect that you execute the command from either a Powershell or a Windows Command shell. This would mean that you don't have a program named `bash.exe` in your PATH. In this case, it is a configuration issue inside your interactive shell and should be asked at i.e. [su].

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. The script itself
2. You’re running the script on windows

**1. The script itself**

The first line should read:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This indicates that this is using bash.
Another posible shell is

```
#!/bin/sh
```

**2.You’re using  Windows**

The bigger issue here is that you’re working with windows.

Bash scripts are designed to work with Unix/Linux operating systems.

The .sh or Shell Scripts file is a type of script file that runs in the Linux operating system. It's analogous to Windows batch files, which are used to run tasks on a computer. Running .sh files in Windows can be done with the help of several programs like Cygwin or the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

For full instructions see here:

https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-run-shell-script-file-in-windows#